# Windows cannot acces Samba share using Map network drive

Tags: windows, debian, samba

I have a system running Debian. I installed Samba on it so I can access a share from Windows 7.

When I try to map a network drive in Windows I get an error: "Windows cannot access \...".

However, I can access the share in Explorer using the same path and credentials.

I'm using the default smb.conf and added:

```
[puppet]
comment = Puppet
read only = no
locking = no
path = /etc/puppet
guest ok = no
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Ideas... Try harder?  Something in smb.conf?  smb signing? Use Google?  Add more info to your question?

Comment: How are you trying to map the network drive?